# Conditional expectation formula for $Y\leq y$

Tags: probability, statistics

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) the conditional expected formula for $X$ and $Y$ continuous random variables with join density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, $Y$'s density $f_Y(y)$, and conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ of $X$ given $Y=y$ is

$E(X|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$

My question is, how does this formula change when $Y\leq y$ instead of $Y=y$?

Answer (score 2):

You want something like $f_{X|Y\leq}(x|y)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(x,a)~da}{\int_{-\infty}^y f_{Y}(a)~da}$, and then $\mathbb E[X|Y\leq y]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X|Y\leq}(x|y)~dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Provided $P(Y\le y)>0$, one has $$E[X\mid Y\le y]=\frac{E[XI(Y\le y)]}{P(Y\le y)}\,,$$ where $I(Y\le y)=1$ if $Y\le y$ and $I(Y\le y)=0$ if $Y>y$.

In your case when marginal, conditional and joint pdfs exist, this can be written as

\begin{align}
E\left[X\mid Y\le y\right]&=\frac1{P(Y\le y)}\iint_{\mathbb R^2} x I(v\le y)f_{X,Y}(x,v)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}v
\\&=\frac1{P(Y\le y)}\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X,Y}(x,v)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}v
\\&=\frac{1}{P(Y\le y)}\int_{-\infty}^y \left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid v)\,\mathrm{d}x \right\}f_Y(v)\,\mathrm{d}v
\end{align}

In other words,

$$E\left[X\mid Y\le y\right]=\frac{\int\limits_{-\infty}^y E\left[X\mid Y=v\right]f_Y(v)\,\mathrm{d}v}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^y  f_Y(v)\,\mathrm{d}v}$$